# Getting Error Submitting Data to DB From iOS app using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ios, database, xcode

I am trying to make it to where I can upload data into a MySQL DB when the user selects save. Everything works fine and uploads perfectly. The only time it doesn't work is if I select one part of the application. At first I thought it was because there was so much information uploading at once that the DB couldn't handle it. Then I realized after doing more research that this is not the case. After further investigating, I am able to NSLog the error and I get this error whenever I try to save:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x8191c20 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8490000 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

If anyone could please help me and try to provide an explanation of what this error means, that would be so helpful. If the explanation alone does not help me I will then post the code but first I would like an explanation and see if I can figure out the problem on my own. Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is what I have in my URL for iOS side. Seems correct to me but I could be missing something:

```
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/signUp.php?prod=%@&comp=%@&phone=%@&cat=%@&autos=%@&notes=%@",prod.text,company.text,phone.text,cat.text,date.text,notes.text];
```

Comment: The URL is incorrect or improperly formatted.  Often seen with characters that aren't escaped properly in the URL.

Comment: @NSBum SO I should look into the URL that I am submitting when making the request or would it be contained in the php file?

Comment: @NSBurn Check edit. If you find it let me know and if you want me to post more let me know

Comment: Yes, but what about escaping the contents of the actual URL params?  Perhaps they contain invalid chars....  Look into `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`  However, if you wanted to post an actual URL that gives the error we could say for sure.

Comment: I've looked at it and have figured out. But now I have another question. The reason it is not working is because the value that I am telling it to send has a number contained in it. (i.e. 5 Years). How do I fix it to make it be able to accept this string value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20542/discussion-between-nsbum-and-zack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/signUp.php?prod=%@&comp=%@&phone=%@&cat=%@&autos=%@&notes=%@",prod.text,company.text,phone.text,cat.text,date.text,notes.text];
NSString *escapedURLStr = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedURLStr];
```

Caveat - not tested.

Comment: Stupid space lol. Works like a charm. Thanks a million for all of the help! +1